# Updating values of a data table column with both assignment operator and string column name does not work

Tags: r, data.table, names

I need to update the values of a column in a data table like so:

```
x[, myvar := make.names(myvar)]
```

This works fine. However, I need to use a string variable with the name of the column now, and this does not seem to work:

```
mystringvar <- "myvar"
x[, get(mystringvar) := make.names(get(mystringvar))]
```

Which is the correct way to do it using a string variable instead of writing the name of the column?

Output: `Error in get(mystringvar) : object 'myvar' not found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Left hand side you don't need `get` using `(column_name)` should work.

```
library(data.table)

x[, (mystringvar) := make.names(get(mystringvar))]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Will accept you answer in 10 minutes (as soon as the site allows me).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `.SDcols`

```
library(data.table)
x[, (mystringvar) := make.names(.SD[[1]]), .SDcols = mystringvar]
```